# How make request GET in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, rxjs

i need request GET from angular to spring java, but i get  error **415**

```
zone.js:3243 GET http://localhost:8080/user/friend/1 415
```

this is my code in spring java to the endpoint

```
 @RequestMapping(
            value = "/friend/{idUser}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            consumes = "application/json",
            produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Friendship>> getFriend(@PathVariable Long idUser) {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Friendship>>(userServiceImpl.getFriends(idUser), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

and this is my code in angular, to request the data from backend

```
getFriends(idUser) {
        console.log('UNA', idUser);
        const config = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        const url = 'http://localhost:8080/user/friend/' + idUser;
        const body = JSON.stringify({"idOwner": idUser});
        return this.http.get<Object[]>(url);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missing config in the http get so your code should be

```
return this.http.get<Object[]>(url, config);
```

Comment: i get this error: [ng] ERROR in src/app/friends/friends.service.ts(22,45): error TS2345: Argument of type 'HttpHeaders' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.

Comment: @ShamPooSham edit your answer pleas, this work beautiful